# How to get schedule in next two weeks by using Google Calendar api?

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-calendar-api

I tried PHP Quickstart (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php) and already signed in and agreed to use my app. So what should I do next? I can't really understand what is structure of the url.
Example (to undestand what I need) in Telegram Bot api it is like: https://api.telegram.org/bot123456789:AAOlm8Wzyr8a5Eumx7EP5xzHCWtK4y75O4I/setwebhook?url=https://example.com/tg/fc.php
Where setWebhook getUpdate is a method. I didn't find instruction of creation this url in the Google's official guide...
All I need is to get info about events in next two weeks, and modify this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to solving this question. All code example can be found from the link provided. Here's a way to resolve your issue:

1. To retrieve Calendar events, within a time-frame (i.e. 2 weeks, etc.), use the [Events.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) resource. This allows you to filter events based on start/end time of the events. See the following parameters as follow:

   - `timeMax` - to set upper bound for an event's start time to filter by.
   - `timeMin` - to set lower bound for an event's end time to filter by.
2. Update/Modify Event details such as description, summary, etc. [Events.patch](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) will allows one to update(s) an event [resource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) by `calendarID` and `eventID`.

You started on the right direction. Just are almost there. Try the techniques suggested above and you should be able to get what you're looking for. Hope this helps and Good luck!